# Error in javascript when double clicking an img element to trigger an click event

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="{CHARSET}">
        <title>imagegame</title>
        <style>
        body { margin: 20px; }
        img { margin: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="pic1" src="img/charpter9/zeroblur.jpg">
        <img id="pic2" src="img/charpter9/oneblur.jpg">
        <img id="pic3" src="img/charpter9/twoblur.jpg">
        <img id="pic4" src="img/charpter9/threeblur.jpg">
        <img id="pic5" src="img/charpter9/fourblur.jpg">
        <img id="pic6" src="img/charpter9/fiveblur.jpg">

        <script>

        function init() {
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
                imgs[i].onclick = onClick;
            }
        }
        function onClick(e){
            var img = e.target;
            var imgsrc = img.src;
            var imgid = img.id;
            var imgsrc0 = imgsrc;
            imgsrc = imgsrc.replace("blur","");
            img.src = imgsrc;
            setTimeout(refresh, 5000, imgsrc0, imgid);
        }

        function refresh(imgsrc,id){
            var img = document.getElementById(id);
            img.setAttribute("src",imgsrc);
        }
        window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

above is the code, my main consideration is whether there is a plan to solve mouse double-click when clicking on one element whose trigger is onclick.

the error I found is when I double-click the image showed on the page, the pic can't be reblurrd automatically. the case is head-first javascript book chapter 9 on about page 142.

thank for your time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX05e.png)

Comment: Even if you set a timeout inside the onClick callback, the event will still be triggered. This may be clumsy, but you may, at the begining of onClick, disable the event for the source, then, after the timeout, re-enable it

Comment: Very similar approach to @Cid suggestion is (I think bootstrap work that way) to add css class to image at beggining of your event like "blurring", and if this class exist dont do anything. Just remember to first check if img have "blurring" class before add it to img. So inside event handler it would be:
1. check if this image have "blurring" class, if it's there do nothing
2. add "blurring" class to img
3. work normally
And in the end of timeout function `refresh` remove this class.

Comment: You can use a 'debouncer' function to limit how often a function can trigger. So if you set the debouncer to 1000ms, spamming the click event will only trigger the real event once per 1000ms of clicking.But changing the logic as explained above would probably be a better solution.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,
I found where is the error, that's because when I double clicked the pics, the onClick function will be executed twice, but at the first time img.src has been changed and not back to blurred one's, so the second time img.src will never back to  blurred one's any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is, that the second time the `src` has no blur anymore already and the time the second timeout is finished it gets set to that `src` instead of the one with the blur.

You could keep the original source in a data-attribute and set the `src` back on that attribute. Furthermore you can cancel the `setTimeout()` on doubleclicks.

```
function onClick(e){
    var img = e.target;
    var imgsrc = img.src;
    var imgid = img.id;
    var imgsrc0 = imgsrc;

    //REM: Keep the original src
    if(!img.getAttribute('data-img-src')){
        img.setAttribute('data-img-src', imgsrc)
    };

    imgsrc = imgsrc.replace("blur","");
    img.src = imgsrc;

    //REM: Clear and reassign the timeout
    clearTimeout(img.timeout); //REM: Dirty way, but fast to show
    img.timeout = setTimeout(refresh, 5000, imgsrc0, imgid)
}

function refresh(imgsrc,id){
    var img = document.getElementById(id);

    //REM: Set the original src
    img.setAttribute("src",img.getAttribute('data-img-src'));
    img.removeAttribute('data-img-src')
}
```

Yet I think it would be much easier to keep all the images in an object and create the `img` on the fly. Also it makes your code unbound from a fixed naming scheme in your image sources. Like this for example:

```js
var _Images = [
  {Blurred: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/172/172838.svg', Active: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/196/196138.svg'},
  {Blurred: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/196/196138.svg', Active: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/172/172838.svg'},
  {Blurred: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/172/172838.svg', Active: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/196/196138.svg'}
];

window.onload = function(){
  for(var i=0, j=_Images.length; i<j; i++){
    var tImage = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    tImage.src = _Images[i].Blurred;
    tImage.setAttribute('width', '20px');
    tImage.onclick = function(image){
      this.src = image.Active;
      
      window.clearTimeout(image.Timeout);
      image.Timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        this.src = image.Blurred
      }.bind(this, image), 5000)
    }.bind(tImage, _Images[i])
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much!  and sorry for the time that you  spend.

Comment: It is fine, check the second example which should make it alot easier.